# CentOS 6 KVM Client to Host network access

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization

I setup a Win2K3 server on a CentOS 6 host and I can ping the Windows Server client at 192.168.122.180 from the host but I cannot ping or otherwise access the host at 192.168.0.138.

I need to access a Samba share on the host and connect to a mysql database on the host.

Do I need some type of firewall change on the host to allow the client to access to host?

Comment: What does your virtual network look like?

Comment: Just the one client @ 192.168.122.180, no other devices. The gateway setup by KVM is 192.168.122.1